# SQL Server - Is there a better way for me to select based on values in varying numbers of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
id     value
1      a
1      x
1      x
2      b
2      b
2      y
3      c
3      d
3      z
10     c
10     c
10     z
11     x
11     y
11     z
```

I want to select id's (duplicate id's are okay) where the value is a, b, or both c and d. So in this case, I would select 1, 2, and 3. Note that duplicate values are possible for each id-value combination.

I have this code that works:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table
WHERE value = 'a' OR value = 'b'

UNION 

SELECT t1.id 
FROM table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.value = 'c' AND t2.value = 'd'
```

But my SQL skills are rusty and I can't shake the feeling that there's a better way to do this. This is going to be a subquery in the middle of some complex legacy code, so I want to be sure that my code is concise and efficient.

Also this question is not a duplicate because it deals with selecting id's based on one row value or two row values at the same time, all the questions I found dealt with selecting based on two row values. I've already solved that issue with the second half of my query.

Comment: @PM77-1 care to elaborate? I'm not seeing how that would work

Comment: I misunderstood your task.

Comment: ah no worries, thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `HAVING`clause with some conditional aggregates will do the trick here:

```
SELECT id
FROM (VALUES(1 ,'a'),
            (1 ,'x'),
            (1 ,'x'),
            (2 ,'b'),
            (2 ,'b'),
            (2 ,'y'),
            (3 ,'c'),
            (3 ,'d'),
            (3 ,'z'),
            (10,'c'),
            (10,'c'),
            (10,'z'),
            (11,'x'),
            (11,'y'),
            (11,'z')) V(id, [value])
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE [value] WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'b' THEN 1 END) > 0
    OR (COUNT(CASE [value] WHEN 'c' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND  COUNT(CASE [value] WHEN 'd' THEN 1 END) > 0);
```

Comment: ahh I knew there was something simple like this that was I missing. Just what I was looking for, thanks!